# Unable to call Child LWC from Parent

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

I have a child LWC named

`pCom_PANS`

I want to call it in another LWC,So I tried  the snippets

`<c-p-com-pANS></c-p-com-pANS>`
`<c-pCom-PANS></c-pCom-PANS>`
`<c-p-com_PANS></c-p-com_PANS>`

But none of them seems to work all throwing deploy error

`force-app\main\default\lwc\lWC_OnboardingProcess\lWC_OnboardingProcess.js  No MODULE named markup://c:pComPans found : [markup://c:lWC_OnboardingProcess]`

The child component is presnt in the target Org.
Is there anything where I am going wrong?

Comment: In [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261169/no-module-named-markup-cbeartile-found) question the problem was having a component defined in VS but not deployed. Maybe that's the reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to put a hyphen before **each** capital letter in the source file name, then lowercase the letter. For your component name, the markup would appear as:

```
<c-p-com_-p-a-n-s></c-p-com_-p-a-n-s>
```

You may want to choose a more practical name for your component, as this name would be frustrating to use.

You can read more about the [naming rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_folder).

> Use camel case to name your component myComponent. Camel case component folder names map to kebab-case in markup. In markup, to reference a component with the folder name myComponent, use `<c-my-component>`.